# How to horizontally align rectangulars when they contain different amount of text

Tags: html, css, display

I've got a problem with aligning 1st rectangular with other two, apparently because it contains less amount of a text. As visible in css, I've set exact dimensions for width and height of rectangulars. Texts will be hyperlinks to different URLs. See screenshot below

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vyg8v.png)

```css
.quote {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.quote #quote-1,
#quote-2 {
  font-size: large;
  text-align: center;
  width: 348.641px;
  height: 84px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 30px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.quote #quote-3 {
  font-size: large;
  text-align: center;
  width: 348.641px;
  height: 84px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 30px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.quote a:link,
a:visited {
  color: #000000;
  background-color: transparent;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.quote a:hover {
  color: #6200ff;
  background-color: transparent;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="quote">
    <div class="quote" id="quote-1">
      <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ONh37dDMJYk" target="_blank">
        <i>"Nobody has done anything without trying,<br />
              you have to try."</i>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="quote" id="quote-2">
      <a href="https://youtube.com/shorts/ExAkkAbwLHY?feature=share" target="_blank"><i
              >Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione
              animi consequuntur sint</i>
              </a>
    </div>
    <div class="quote" id="quote-3">
      <a href="https://youtube.com/shorts/YAelHsS0p38?feature=share" target="_blank">
        <i>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione
              animi consequuntur sint
            </i>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

I´ve tried to set different display values, but still got no clue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is where [`display: flex`](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) comes in handy, specifically it's [alignment capabilities](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox#alignment_justification_and_distribution_of_free_space_between_items)

Update your `.quote` css to this:

```
.quote {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i fixed your code, just copy this and everything will  work fine, i fixed content to be centered in the .quote container:

```
.quote {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.quote #quote-1,
#quote-2 {
  font-size: large;
  text-align: center;
  width: 348.641px;
  height: 84px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 30px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.quote #quote-3 {
  font-size: large;
  text-align: center;
  width: 348.641px;
  height: 84px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 30px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.quote a:link,
a:visited {
  color: #000000;
  background-color: transparent;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.quote a:hover {
  color: #6200ff;
  background-color: transparent;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Flex is good but it's always worthwhile understanding why your first div was lower in the example you gave. Inline divs are, by default, aligned to the text baseline. As you can see from your screenshot, the bottom rows of text are all at the same height. The div has been moved down to ensure the text baseline across all three divs are at the same height.

[image]

To solve this, if you've fixed the height of the divs then just add `vertical-align: top` to your divs. See marked-up code below

```css
/* added this class so you can see it's the children divs that need the vertical-alignment property set */
.vertical-top {
  vertical-align:top;
}

.quote {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.quote #quote-1,
#quote-2 {
  font-size: large;
  text-align: center;
  width: 348.641px;
  height: 84px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 30px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.quote #quote-3 {
  font-size: large;
  text-align: center;
  width: 348.641px;
  height: 84px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 30px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.quote a:link,
a:visited {
  color: #000000;
  background-color: transparent;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.quote a:hover {
  color: #6200ff;
  background-color: transparent;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="quote">
    <div class="quote vertical-top" id="quote-1"><!-- added class vertical-top -->
      <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ONh37dDMJYk" target="_blank">
        <i>"Nobody has done anything without trying,<br />
              you have to try."</i>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="quote vertical-top" id="quote-2"><!-- added class vertical-top -->
      <a href="https://youtube.com/shorts/ExAkkAbwLHY?feature=share" target="_blank"><i
              >Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione
              animi consequuntur sint</i>
              </a>
    </div>
    <div class="quote vertical-top" id="quote-3"><!-- added class vertical-top -->
      <a href="https://youtube.com/shorts/YAelHsS0p38?feature=share" target="_blank">
        <i>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione
              animi consequuntur sint
            </i>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```